# Не загружаются картинки в слайдер через панель администартора

Tags: django-admin, django-model

Кто-то может подсказать в чем может быть дело

1. Cоздано приложение cms где зарегистрирован класс для прогрузки картинок в слайдере на странице
2. В админке это приложение появилось. Миграции выполнены.
   Картинки загружены через админку
   [image: Адмнка сервера]
   Картинки отображаются в проекте
   [image: В проекте]
3. Идет попытка загрузки картинок в слайдер через рендер вьюхи
   [image: Во вьюхе]

[image: На html-странице со слайдером]
4. Вроде в урл и сеттингс все прописала
[image: сеттинг]

[image: урл]
5. При загрузке страницы картинки не прогружаются
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/sliderimage/6.jpg
Using the URLconf defined in DjangoProject.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
admin/
addmsg/ [name='pagemsg']
The current path, media/sliderimage/6.jpg, didn’t match any of these.

Не могу понять, где накосячила

Похоже надо что-то в урлы прописать, но не пойму что.

Comment: [Почему не следует выкладывать код/данные/ошибки в виде скриншотов?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12120/385375)